# Middleware not working when created route from routeserviceprovider in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Create the Route file from the Route Service Provide and assign the middleware "admin.auth" and this middleware working in the web.php giving the basic information of the admin user but from the custom.php it is returning auth false. How can admin.auth will work from route service provider

```
 protected function mapWebRoutes2()
    {
        Route::group([
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => 'custom',
            'middleware' => 'admin.auth'
        ], function ($router) {

            require base_path('routes/custom.php');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to include the `web` middleware, otherwise the default authentication won't work since the session etc. is not started:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes2()
{
    Route::group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'custom',
        'middleware' => ['web', 'admin.auth']
    ], function () {
        require base_path('routes/custom.php');
    });
}
```

or shorter:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes2()
{
    Route::prefix('custom')
        ->middleware(['web', 'admin.auth'])
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/custom.php'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with copy of existing example for api routes. In your example something like:

```
/**
 * Define the "custom" routes for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes2()
{
    Route::prefix('custom')
        ->middleware(['admin.auth'])
        ->namespace($this->namespace)
        ->group(base_path('routes/custom.php'));
}
```

Comment: If it helped you feel free to accept the answer. :) 
Always go with [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). What's seen in file itself just replicate and use. #SOreadytohelp

Comment: it's is not working with by this method. If i add file in web.php to make different file to route it's works require __DIR__ . '/affirmate.php';

Comment: Why would you do that? Make which ever file you need in `routes` directory location. Then you can add all of those in `RouteServiceProvider`. Problem solved. I used it more than once this way and it works very well plus it is well separated and decoupled.

Comment: Failed this way I put here?